# How to create a dataframe from csv file with texts separated by pipe I?

Tags: r

I have a csv file with patient's data, but all the data is written in a single column, named `id_paciente|dt_coleta|de_origem|de_exame|de_analito|de_resultado|cd_unidade|de_valor_referencia`, in text separated by a string |, as the image shows

[image: csv file with patiennts]

I'd like to convert it to multiple columns with the title "id_patient", "dt_exame" and so on, so I can properly work on it.

So it's basically written as

```
id_paciente
202018|13/06/2020|HOSP|PCR em tempo real para detecção de Coron|Resultado COVID-19:|Não detectado|NULL|Não detectado            
202025|11/05/2020|HOSP|Sorologia SARS-CoV-2/COVID19 IgG/IgM|IgG                                                                 
202025|11/05/2020|HOSP|Sorologia SARS-CoV-2/COVID19 IgG/IgM|COVID IgG Interp|Não reagente|NULL|                                 
202025|11/05/2020|HOSP|PCR em tempo real para detecção de Coron|Resultado COVID-19:|Não detectado|NULL|Não detectado            
202025|11/05/2020|HOSP|Sorologia SARS-CoV-2/COVID19 IgG/IgM|IgM                                                                 
202025|11/05/2020|HOSP|Sorologia SARS-CoV-2/COVID19 IgG/IgM|COVID IgM Interp|Não reagente|NULL|
```

I've tried using tidyr::separate, but I couldn't work my way around it by doing

```
df %>% separate(id_paciente.dt_coleta.de_origem.de_exame.de_analito.de_resultado.cd_unidade.de_valor_referencia, c("id_paciente", "dt_coleta", "de_origem", "de_exame", "de_analito", "de_resultado", "cd_unidade", "de_valor_referencia"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When reading the data, why not `read.csv(sep="|")`?  Is there a reason you defer processing to `dplyr`?

Comment: I agree with Limey. Another option is to use `fread` from the `data.table` package which intelligently chooses the correct separator and removes header lines automatically.

Comment: No special reason, I just was unaware one could do it, since it's been only a month since I started to learn R. Ian, would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, first you need to install the package with `install.packages("data.table")`. Once it's installed, load it with `library(data.table)`. Then `data <- fread("myfile.csv")`.

Comment: It does! Thank you so much!

Comment: `df <- read.csv(file="<myFileName>.csv", sep="|")` should give you the data frame you need, with each row already separated into the variables you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Limey and Ian!